# Equation of a dotted circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, math-software

What is happening in this dotted circle? $x^2+y^2 < 2x$

I don't understand how this forms this dotted circle that I get when I type this into geogebra.

Comment: Could you please add a picture describing your problem?

Comment: I don't have any problem for your expression in my copy of GeoGebra. It automatically color the interior in blue. In any event, you can always right click the circle, select "Object Properties" -> "Color" and change the opacity yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2\lt 2x&\iff x^2-2x+y^2\lt 0\\&\iff(x^2-2x+1)+y^2\lt 1\\&\iff(x-1)^2+y^2\lt1.\end{align}$$
This represents the inside of the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ without its circumference.

Comment: Hm, why doesn't geogebra color the area inside the circle? It just makes this 'dotted' circle that makes no sense.

Comment: Well, don't know about it. My answer is just about what the inequality means.

Comment: @mathlove I'm not a Geogebra wizard or anything, but a dotted line is conventionally used to denote a bounded region which does not include the boundary.  If you changed '<' to '<=' I'd expect to see the dotted line become solid.